# Detect right and left shift keys pressed together from within Awesome WM

Tags: linux, gnome, awesome-wm

I want to have Awesome WM run a command when both Shift keys (left and right) are pressed together.

I know Linux can differentiate between the two shift keys (e.g., one can tell Gnome to change the keyboard layout when both Shift keys are pressed together).

Is there a way to do this in Awesome?

Comment: See an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/565407/detect-right-and-left-shift-keys-pressed-together-from-within-awesome-wm

Answer (score 0):

It is realy very simple, you can set the "Shift" (left shift) as mod key and #62 (right shift) as pressed key. Tested it just now and with me it works.
for instance if I want firefox to spawn I do this:

```
awful.key({ "Shift" }, "#62", function () awful.util.spawn(browser) end),
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, this is the same as the answer in http://askubuntu.com/questions/565407/detect-right-and-left-shift-keys-pressed-together-from-within-awesome-wm.  One problem with this solution, though, is that if one presses right shift before left shift, it does not work.